# redirect to homepage using php after submiting form with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

This is my first time using ajax with php . I have a register form where I check if the entered username already exists in a mongodb database . If it does then I show an error in my page , else I want to redirect to my index.php and start a session .

EDIT : I changed my script completely now I redirect succesfully .
The angularJS warning is gone !

register.php where I send my data for validation UPDATED!

```
 $("#registerForm").submit((e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            var uname = $("#username").val();
            var fname = $("#firstname").val();
            var lname = $("#lastname").val();
            var addr = $("#address").val();
            var pw = $("#password").val();
            var sub = $("#submitRegister").val();
            var errorSubmit = $("#checkSubmitError").val();
            $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              data:{username:uname,firstname:fname,
                    lastname:lname,address:addr, password:pw ,
                    submitRegister:sub , checkSubmitError: errorSubmit },
              url:'insertUser.php',
              success:(data)=>{
                if(data == 'success'){
                  window.location.href = '../php/index.php';
                }else if(data =='failed'){
                    $("#username").val(""); //empty username field
                    var submitErr = $("#checkSubmitError");
                    var isHidden =submitErr.hasClass("hide");
                    if(isHidden){
                      submitErr.removeClass("hide");
                      submitErr.addClass("show");
                    }else{
                      submitErr.removeClass("hide");
                      submitErr.addClass("show");
                    }
                }
              },
              error: (xhr)=>{
                alert("error");
              },

            });
          });



 <body>
       <form action = "insertUser.php" method= "POST" id ="registerForm" name= "regForm">
           ...my inputs with ids 
          <!-- button that submits form  -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id = "submitRegister" name="submit" 
           >Submit
          </button> 
        <!--hidden error I display if username exists --> 
        <span id ="checkSubmitError" class= "hide text-danger"> </span>
       </form>
  </body>
```

Then in my insertUser.php where I check if username exists in my db UPDATED!

```
<?php

  require '../vendor/autoload.php';


  if(isset($_POST['submitRegister'])){
    $m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
    $db = $m ->ECommerce;
  
    $collection = $db->users;
    //check if username already exists 
    $alreadyExists = false;
    $check = $collection->find(array('userName'=>$_POST['username']));
    $count=0;
    if(is_array($check) || is_object($check)){
      foreach($check as $i){ 
        $count= $count+1;
      }
    }
    if($count==0){
   
      $document = array(
        "firstName" => $_POST['firstname'],
        "lastName" => $_POST['lastname'],
        "address" => $_POST['address'],
        "userName" => $_POST['username'],
        "password" => password_hash($_POST['password'] ,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
      );
    
    
      $collection->insertOne($document); //inserts succesfully 
      $response = "success";
      echo $response;
      exit();
    
      
    }else{
      $alreadyExists = true;
      $response = "failed";
      echo $response;
      exit();
    }

  
  }
  

?>
```

Comment: After a `header('Location:...` you should always have an `exit;` as `header()` sends a header to the browser, it does not terminate execution of the script. Not sure that is whats causing your problem in this case, but it should be there anyway

Comment: @RiggsFolly did not work still got tried to load AngluarJS more than once and I stay in register page

Comment: Aa far as I know, `.load()`-makes a GET request, not a POST request. This should be a POST request, so you might want to rethink the method and use `$.ajax()` or `$.post()` instead.

Comment: @vasilis is there still a question after your edit? If not then please post reply the solution and accept it as the good solution please.

Comment: @PedroFerreira I can in 2 days

Answer (score 0):

The code I edited in my example now works perfectly . It is over .
What I learned :

`$ajax` is better than `$load` method for redirecting .
To return data to `success()` function you `echo  $data` in the php script then `exit()` .

These were the keypoints here .